# MongoJS add to existing array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongojs

I am trying to add to an existing array in my mongoDB. Here is what I have, but it is of course incorrect because all the data gets wiped out after it tries to add it:

```
db.cardKeeper.update(
        {_id: ObjectId('5621c5ac30895e5776e4d1ea')},
        {
            $push:{'cardKeeperApp.appData.cardDecks':deckObject}
        }
    )
```

`deckObject` which is the object I am trying to add to the array looks like this

```
var deckObject = {
        name: productName,
        searchName: productItem,
        price:{
            purchasePrice: productCost,
            averageWorth: priceAverageFixed,
            lowWorth: lowestSoldAmount,
            highWorth: highestSoldAmount
        }
    }
```

and as you can see `cardKeeperApp.appData.cardDecks` is my array which holds more info that looks just like `deckObject`

If it helps here is the full object, I am trying to add to the `cardDecks` array. I have marked fields as null

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5635ddf82f4c220f4f932af2"),
    "cardKeeperApp" : {
        "appData" : {
            "cardDecks" : [
                {
                    "name" : "Some Name",
                    "searchName" : "Some+Name",
                    "price" : {
                        "purchasePrice" : null,
                        "averageWorth" : null,
                        "lowWorth" : null,
                        "highWorth" : null
                    }
                }
            ],
            "allDeckTotalWorth" : null
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. `findAndModify` by `query:{_id:ObjectId}` and then update and push:

```
db.cardKeeper.findAndModify({query:{_id: ObjectId('5635ddf82f4c220f4f932af2')},
    update: {$push:{'cardKeeperApp.appData.cardDecks': deckObject}},
    new:true}, function (err, doc) {
        res.json(doc);
    });
```